# convert multiple files from .LWO to .OBJ or similar

Tags: stl, processing

I need to convert many files from .lwo format to .obj or .stl. I have too many to convert "by hand", meaning I don't want to use online tools or import/export the files one by one in Blender or similar.

So I'm trying to do so with a program that would load up each file, convert, then save a new stl . The files are numbered "file000001", "file000002", etc. to make importing easier.

Is there any program out there that will do this? If not, how would I go about accomplishing my goal?

As far as languages go, I am most effective with Processing/Java. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727786/converting-obj-file-to-vbo-using-javascript) which might be similar but doesn't relate to LWOs.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're going to either have to understand the contents of each file type and do the conversion yourself, or find a converter that will run via the command prompt and use that programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you can find a few editors that import .lwo and export .obj
For example, [Wings3D](http://www.wings3d.com/) does that and free/opensource/lightweight.
Wings is scriptable using erlang.

Blender has [LWO importer](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/LightWave_Object) too, but it's not enabled by default. you need to go to Preferences > Addons and enable it there:
[image: blender .lwo import]
Blender has a [Python API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/) which should be easy to pickup.
This would allow you to write a script that does a batch conversion (reads a directory, traverses files, imports .lwo, transforms (scales/rotates if needed), exports .obj)

Perhaps if you search enough maybe there is a 3d file format batch converter already out there and .lwo/.obj are old enough formats so might be likely to be supported.

If you want to implement something from scratch, you need to look into each file format (e.g. [lightwave object](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/lightwave/), [obj](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/) ) to be able to parse and export.
Hopefully there's a java library that for you. I'd start with a 3D java game engine. For example here's a [java .LWO importer found via JMonkey](https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/lwo-hps-asset-loaders/14591).

Answer (score 1):

I just found [assimp](http://www.assimp.org/main_features.html) which has a command line tool to convert different file types. Thanks everyone who answered!